# rails application on nginx server switch from 81 to 80 after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean, nginx-location

I have deployed two rails application on same IP address one is running on port 80 and another on port 81.
I am running application that is deployed on port 81. 
Here i am facing problem, that after logout and sighnup.
IP address switched to port 80.

> that is if i am on IP 139.XX.X.XX:81, it switched to IP 139.XX.X.XX

Here is my configuration file that is inside site-enabled:

```
upstream landing_app {
    server unix:///home/deploy/www/application_1/shared/tmp/sockets/application_1-puma.sock;
}

upstream const_app {
   server unix:///home/deploy/www/application_2/shared/tmp/sockets/application_2-puma.sock;
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name 139.XX.X.XX application_1.in www.application_1.in; # change to match your URL
    root /www/application_1/current/public; # I assume your app is located at this location

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    client_body_buffer_size     32k;
    client_header_buffer_size   8k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;
    location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
        proxy_pass http://landing_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }



}

server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 139.XX.X.XX stage.application_2.in www.stage.application_2.in; # change to match your URL
    root /www/application_2/current/public; # I assume your app is located at this location

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    client_body_buffer_size     32k;
    client_header_buffer_size   8k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 200;
        proxy_pass http://const_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

}
```

Comment: Try to remove the ip address from the `server_name` directive

Comment: By the way, why do you want to listen on :80 and :81 ? Why not just use the different server name to differentiate your apps ?